# Apple 30" display and iMac 27"

Tags: imac, display, cinema-display

I have an iMac i7 27" 2012 and I want to use it with my 30" Apple display.

I have tried Apple's Mini Display Port to Dual-Link DVI Adapter, but that did not work. I have also tried Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter but that only displays the 30" screen at 1920x1200 - the native resolution of the Apple 30" display is 2560x1600 so the resolution isn't correct.

Is there any way I can get the 30" Apple display to show at it's native resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [tech spec page](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP634) for the Late 2011 iMac and the new thin iMac say that they both support both the built in monitor and an external monitor at up to 2560X1600. It seems like the Mini display port to Dual Link DVI adapter should work. [This conversation](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10623026) on Apple's support site concurs.

Double check all of your connections, try rebooting with the monitor plugged in and if you still can't get it to work try taking to to a genius bar if you have an Apple retail story nearby.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different Theo. If you haven't been on a stack exchange site before be sure to read the FAQs. Good luck with your problem.